# Textblock does not update databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to show an int in a textblock and this should update. I'm doing this by databinding. This is my code in MainPage.xaml (Windows Store app)

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <Models:PlayBoard />
</Grid.DataContext>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Score, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I think that this should work, but it doesn't update when Score changes value. The textblock just stays at 0

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGpdt.png)

Comment: did you set the textbox. datacontext?

Comment: I'm not using a textbox. I just set the Grid.DataContext (which should be correct since the textbox is in the grid). And I think this works because it shows 0 at the start, which is the initial value of int Score.

Comment: Did you raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` when `Score` changed? Show us the implementation of the property in `Playboard`.

Comment: Oh no I didn't do that. Score is quite simple. Each time a rectangle is clicked, it adds +1 to the score.

Comment: Btw it's a `TextBlock` it doesn't go `TwoWay`s, because it only displays.

Comment: I just tried using TwoWay because OneWay didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

you ned to do it like this

```
 <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="195,116,0,0" Name="Box"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,119,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Block" 
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=Box, Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```